# schedulercontext quartz.net

Tags: scheduler, quartz.net

I have several jobs scheduled with Quartz.net.  I have the same job detail being repeated for every job like the email address, user id....
Each job may have a different trigger so I cannot really put the job detail in each trigger.

Is there some other place like the schedulingcontext where I can put the common information once instead of repeating for each job?
If  yes, can someone please provide a sample of the xml that will be used by quartz.

Pratik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information can be stored only on trigger and job detail level and later it can be accessed as combined map in the job. If you want global information like this I would advice to use .NET configuration section and abstract it with you you configuration facade.